# Split and print the word before and after the \ of *n of lines, from a txt to two different txt's

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, split, txt

I searched around a bit, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my needs.
I'm new to python, so I'm sorry if what I'm asking is pretty obvious.

I have a .txt file (for simplicity I will call it inputfile.txt) with a list of names of folder\files like this:

```
camisos\CROWDER_IMAG_1.mov
camisos\KS_HIGHENERGY.mov
camisos\KS_LOWENERGY.mov
```

What I need is to split the first word (the one before the `\`) and write it to a txt file (for simplicity I will call it outputfile.txt).

Then take the second (the one after the `\`) and write it in another txt file.

This is what i did so far:

```
 with open("inputfile.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("outputfile.txt", "w") as new_f:
        for line in lines:
            text = input()
            print(text.split()[0])
```

This in my mind should print only the first word in the new txt, but I only got an empty txt file without any error.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks in advance for any help you could give me.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at `os.path` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Comment: I've checked it, but in my case, the path is inside a txt file and not the path itself. Maybe I didn't understand exactly how os.path works.

Comment: `os.path.basename(text)` should return the filename only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file in a list of strings and split each string to create 2 separate lists.

```
with open("inputfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

X = []
Y = []

for line in lines:
    X.append(line.split('\\')[0] + '\n')
    Y.append(line.split('\\')[1])

with open("outputfile1.txt", "w") as f1:
    f1.writelines(X)

with open("outputfile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.writelines(Y)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for that. One question: if [0] return the first word, [-1] the last, what does 1 do?

Comment: n represents (n+1)th element. So [1]  will return 2nd element. In this case, 2nd is the last element.